# How to wrap final tempate class from C++ using swig?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, swig

I am trying to wrap a template which is marked as final from C++ to C# without success. Swig will say "Template 'Test' undefined"

It works if I remove the final keyword but the header isn't under my control.

```
%module SwigTest
template <typename T>
class Test final
{
    public:
    T a;
};
%template(TestBool)  Test <bool>;
```

Does the final effect the name in any way? I tried

```
%template(TestBool)  Test final <bool>;
```

and similar combinations but no success.

Comment: Maybe swig not updated to know about c++11 keywords?

Comment: Might be true. Going to ask them directly if no one has a solution. Not sure if bug or I am just doing it wrong :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like SWIG doesn't understand `final` yet. You can trivially work around this with the pre-processor in SWIG though:

```
%module SwigTest

#define final

template <typename T>
class Test final
{
    public:
    T a;
};
%template(TestBool)  Test <bool>;
```

This will work with no negative impact.